# jQuery disable double click prevention breaking functionality of a PHP function in a form

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, forms

I have a jquery bug that I cant solve - hoping for help with a solution. Dont know if it is browser bug related (probably not), jQuery related, or Yii (our backend) related - but I need to try to solve it with the jQuery portion. Code at bottom of message.

**Requirement:** Disable accidental double submissions on forms.

**Current Solution:** Check for form submission state through a delegate and when the DOM form state changes to submit - append the disable attribute to the form submit button to prevent accident double form submission.

**jQuery double click disabler:**

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
$('html').delegate('form', 'submit', function() {
$(this).find(':submit').attr('disabled', true);
});
});
```

**Problem:** This works perfectly on every part of the CRM we are developing EXCEPT for a single timekeeper (clock in/clock out) feature. With the timekeeper the form has two submit buttons (one for clock in, one for clock out). Only one submit button shows at a time (Either "In" or "Out". When you click the button - it submits the form and changes the submit button to the other state by checking a session var to determine what state it is in and determines which of the two submit buttons are to be displayed. Problem is if you click it, the form appears to submit, but the state don't change. If you click it really fast a few times you can get it to change state. I suspect this is a timing or order of operations issue, but I have no idea how to fix it. The fix MUST be done on the front end, so here is the code (both the PHP being impacted and jQuery double click prevention). Perhaps a different method of disabling double submissions may work, please post your solution if you have one to try. Commenting out the current jQuery allows the form to function as designed. What might be causing this, and how might I change the jQuery double click prevention to solve it?

**On page PHP for the time clock:**

```
<form action = "<?=$clockUrl?>" method = "post" >
<input type = "hidden" name = "previousUrl" value = "<?=$currentUrl?>">
<?php if ($sessionVar->timeclockin) {?>
<input type = "submit" name = "submit-clockout" value = "Out">
<class="clock-time" ><?=$sessionVar->timeclockin?></class="clock-time">
<?php } else {?>
<input type = "submit" name = "submit-clockin" value = "In">
<?php }?>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Update 1:**

If you are looking to prevent the button from being pressed twice then inside of your onclick or submit function, you should use something similar to the following:

```
$('#yourButton').prop('disabled', true);
```

If the page then redirects then you won't have to undo this. If it does, then do the opposite by changing true to false.

---

The submit function should instead disable the submit button until it either returns or fails.

An alternative is to use a lambda style function and replace it temporarily with an empty function until the request returns or fails.

Comment: The page completely reloads on submit, so it is only in the disabled state until the page reloads. When the page reloads, the buttons are back in the default enabled state - so this problem is happening sometime between clicking submit and the page refresh - almost as if the form is submitting without actually sending the info on what button was actually clicked. 

Do you have an code example of what you are proposing?

Comment: I can generate some if you like.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for pointing me in the right direction Tyler! I was able to fix the issue with the following alteration to my script.

```
    function do_nothing() {
    console.log("click prevented");
    return false;
    }

    $('html').delegate('form', 'submit', function(e) {
       $(e.target).find(':submit').click(do_nothing);
       setTimeout(function(){
       $(e.target).unbind('click', do_nothing);
       }, 10000);
    });
```